# Go lang strong typed name of a field

Tags: go, reflection

I have a go struct that I use to serialize to bson and store in mongodb.

When I make queries, set up indexes, etc very often I need to refer to the field name or the bson tag of it.

Is there a compile time validatable way to do that?

Say if I have the struct:

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar string `bson:"bar"`
}
```

then

```golang
query = fmt.SPrintf("%s = 'aaa'", Foo.Bar.GetTag("bson"))
```

Note I am aware that I can do

```golang
query = fmt.SPrintf("%s = 'aaa'", refect.TypeOf(Foo{}).GetField("Bar").GetTag("bson"))
```

but that is not what I am looking for. In this last variant if I rename the field `Bar` to `Baz` I am not going to get compile time error, because I referred to the name as a string literal.

Comment: as far as I know, you cannot catch this error as tags are assigned at runtime.

Comment: Oh, I guess code generation again to the rescue. It seems golang was designed without fully understanding the power of strong typing and compile time checks.

I cannot believe that I have no way to explain to golang that I expect a type to be implementing a particular interface and get compile-time errors if the contract gets broken.